# Is there a way to get custom properties panel in a custom t panel?

Tags: python, scripting

I already created a custom t panel and use the custom properties often, was hoping to add them to the panel, but do not know how to grab the custom properties panel and copy it to my t panel.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer from [Custom properties on an action, any place for UI visibility?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67851/custom-properties-on-an-action-any-place-for-ui-visibility)

Add a custom property panel to the Action Editor, much the same way as it is added to other parts of the UI.  Import the `rna_prop_ui.PropertyPanel` class and set the path from context to `"object.animation_data.action"` and the type to `bpy.types.Action`.

The default `bl_label` if not defined  is "Custom Properties".

[image]

```
import bpy

from bpy.types import Panel
from rna_prop_ui import PropertyPanel


class ACTION_PT_custom_props(PropertyPanel, Panel):
    bl_label = "Action Properties"
    bl_idname = "ACTION_PT_custom_props"
    bl_space_type = 'DOPESHEET_EDITOR'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    # required for PropertyPanel
    #COMPAT_ENGINES = {'BLENDER_RENDER', 'BLENDER_GAME'}
    _context_path = "object.animation_data.action"
    _property_type = bpy.types.Action

    @classmethod
    def poll(self, context):
        obj = getattr(context, "object", None)
        ad = getattr(obj, "animation_data", None)
        action = getattr(ad, "action", None)
        return action is not None

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ACTION_PT_custom_props)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ACTION_PT_custom_props)

if __name__ == "__main__":  # only for live edit.
    register()
```

Note this example is for actions. For object

```
    _context_path = "object"
    _property_type = bpy.types.Object
```

Comment: You are the best. Thank you so much!!